# Hibernate Foreign Key Constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to create to SQL database tables named **Customer** and **Orders**
SQL :

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  customer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);


CREATE TABLE Orders (
  order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_name VARCHAR(255),
  order_date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_name) REFERENCES Customer(customer_name)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Afterwards I want to insert an Orders object with a reference to the Customer object.
Java & Hibernate:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Customer cu = (Customer) session.load(Customer.class, 1);

Date d = new Date();
Orders od = new Orders(cu, d);
od.setCustomer(cu);

Set<Orders> hs = new HashSet<Orders>();
hs.add(od);
cu.setOrderses(hs);

 session.save(cu);
 session.save(od);
 tx.commit();
```

The insert returns an exception : 
*Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails*
I am doing everything exactly as in the Hibernate Tutorials. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Java classes

```
    public class Customer  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer customerId;
     private String customerName;
     private Set<Orders> orderses = new HashSet<Orders>(0);

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String customerName, Set<Orders> orderses) {
       this.customerName = customerName;
       this.orderses = orderses;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
    public Set<Orders> getOrderses() {
        return this.orderses;
    }

    public void setOrderses(Set<Orders> orderses) {
        this.orderses = orderses;
    }

}

    public class Orders  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer orderId;
     private Customer customer;
     private Date orderDate;

    public Orders() {
    }

    public Orders(Customer customer, Date orderDate) {
       this.customer = customer;
       this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public Integer getOrderId() {
        return this.orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(Integer orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return this.customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return this.orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you don't think you need to save orders explicitly, hibernate will do it for you when you save the customer.

Comment: I tried both ways: Using Cascades and without: Both return the same exception

Comment: Can you share the code for the **Customer** and **Orders** classes please?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using customer_name as the foreign key instead of the customer_id?

Comment: customer_name is an alternative unique key which contains the relevant name

Comment: The customer object is actually already in the database that is why i am doing session.load. I am trying to update the object.

Comment: This error has happened in your case because, you are explicitly trying to save Customer and Order data, But commiting in the same transaction. Normally, you must have an instance of Order class as an attribute in customer  instead and have invoked save method at one by setting the order class properties in customer class itself. In your way,if you want to achieve this functionality, explicitly save customer class, Commit the transaction & being next transaction for order class and save it. It will work.

Comment: The error also occurs when I am only doing one save(cu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the property-ref attribute found here:
http://learningviacode.blogspot.de/2012/01/foreign-key-referencing-nonprimary-keys.html